# Put an OpenID and Google Account Login in a Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I'm starting in the Rails world and i want to know how to put an login system like that here in Stack Overflow uses. Thanks, and remember that i'm starting, and if you can post a link to a very good tutorial, is very nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/tree/master#readme). There is a nice [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic) on implementing it ([ASCIIcast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic) version available too).
Using an OpenID with it seems preety simple, according to the [docs](http://rdoc.info/projects/binarylogic/authlogic):

```
UserSession.create(:openid_identifier => "identifier", :remember_me => true)
```